# The type or namespace name 'DataSet' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am learning how to write code in asp.net and this is my first crack at it. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

These are the errors I keep getting when I run this code.

> (16:9) The type or namespace name 'DataSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   (16:27) The type or namespace name 'DataSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   (17:9) The type or namespace name 'DataSetTableAdapters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   (17:62) The type or namespace name 'DataSetTableAdapters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   (19:27) The name 'Login1' does not exist in the current context
>   (20:27) The name 'Login1' does not exist in the current context

**login.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body background="images\reading.jpg">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><font size="6" color="white"><center>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">
        </asp:Login>
    </font></center></div>

        <div><p><font size="6" color="white"><center>Are you a new user? Please<center></font></p></div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"><font size="6" color="red"><center>Sign Up</center></font></asp:LinkButton>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet lds = new DataSet();
        DataSetTableAdapters.LoginTableAdapter loginTA = new DataSetTableAdapters.LoginTableAdapter();
        loginTA.Fill(lds.Login);
        string userName = Login1.UserName;  
        string password = Login1.Password;
        if (userName != null)
        {
            var pwd = from login in lds.Login
                      where userName.Contains(login.user_name)
                      select login.pwd;
            foreach (var item in pwd)
            {
                if (item == password)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("files.aspx");
                }

            }

        }
    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("signup.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: include assembly `System.Data` in project and add line `using System.Data` in code

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the line `using System.Data;` near the other `using` statements. This will allow your class to access the DataSet class without fully qualifying the class name.

Each time you see the error

> The type or namespace name ... could not be found

You need to identify the namespace where the class is defined and add a using statement for said namespace. Another option is to include the namespace when using the class but that wouldn't work for extension methods.

A good Visual Studio tip is to right click on the class names that are giving you these errors, you should see  Quick Fix option to automatically add the required `using` statement.

Comment: i still get these errors The type or namespace name 'DataSetTableAdapters' could not be found 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'Login' and no extension method 'Login' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: also what is wrong with this? The name 'Login1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: thank you , what about the does not exist in the current context?

Comment: i could quick fix all but this one "public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page" still getting the namespace error

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `System.Data` reference up top with `using System.Data;`

Comment: `using System.Data` isn't a reference. That's just adding the namespace to be in scope in that file.

Comment: can you write me  a sample login code for reference?